# Not able to see the selected value in the combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a C#/WPF application.
I'm invoking ProcessServiceResponse() method in MainViewModel on click of a button.
SelectedCountry property value is correctly getting set in this method.The country list combobox is also showing the list of countries.
But somehow, am not seeing a selected value(for e.g. SG) in the country dropdown list.
Any ideas as to what am I missing here please?
Let me know if you need any other details around the code.

Thanks.

Here's my code.

```
MainWindow View:

<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:MainViewModel="clr-namespace:MyTool.ViewModels"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:MyTool.ViewModel.Bonds"
        xmlns:View="clr-namespace:MyTool" x:Class="MyTool.MainWindow"
        Title="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Height="600" Width="1100">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <MainViewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>


<ComboBox Margin="1,0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModel.CountryList,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Code" SelectedItem="{Binding MyViewModel.SelectedCountry, Mode=TwoWay}" TabIndex="2" Grid.Row="7"  Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" />

MainViewModel:

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    MyAttributes = new MyViewModel();

}

public object MyAttributes
        {
            get { return m_myViewModel; }
            set
            {
                m_myViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyAttributes");
            }
        }

public void ProcessServiceResponse()

{

        var destination = new MyViewModel();/
            Type destinationType = destination.GetType();

            PropertyInfo[] destinationTypePI = destinationType.GetProperties();

            string propertyName = string.Empty;
            object propertyValue = null;

            foreach (var pinfo in sourcePI)
            {
                propertyName = pinfo.Name.Trim();
                var matchingItem = destinationTypePI.ToList().Where(d => d.Name == propertyName);
                if (matchingItem != null && matchingItem.Count() > 0)
                {
                    propertyValue = pinfo.GetValue(serviceResponse.lst_DKSecurities[0]);
                    matchingItem.FirstOrDefault().SetValue(destination, propertyValue);                    
                }

            }

            this.MyAttributes = destination;

}

MyViewModel:

namespace MyTool.ViewModels;
public class MyViewModel
{

public MyViewModel
{
 this.CountryList = GetCountryList();
}

public string SelectedCountry
        {
            get
            {
                return m_selectedCountry;
            }
            set
            {
                m_selectedCountry = value;
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you fill the CountryList, assign to the SelectedCountry the list item you want to display:

```
 CountryList = new ObservableCollection<string> {"A", "B", "C"};
        SelectedCountry = CountryList[0];

 <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"         
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Rom for your inputs.But am afraid this wont work as the list item value that I want to display is only available in ProcessServiceResponse() method in my MainViewModel.And am fetching the countries list in the constructor of MyViewModel which gets called before ProcessServiceResponse()  method gets invoked.